# Can't get the right include path in PHP

Tags: php, include, compiler-errors, require

I read some other related questions and thought this was the best answer:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR."/path/to/program/root");
```

However, I can't get it to the right directory and the error messages aren't helpful enough, so I'm lost. My user area directory (shared host) looks like this:

```
/home/linweb09/b/example.com-1050560306/user    # <-- this is my root
```

I was trying to re-organise my program so that all of the model files go in this directory:

```
{root}/program_name/library/
```

The web-root folder is this:

```
{root}/htdocs/
```

So I changed all of my includes to look like this:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR
                 ."/home/linweb09/b/example.com-1050360506/user");
require_once "/program_name/library/some_module.php";
```

The index has to load this include to work, to authenticate the user:

```
/htdocs/admin/authenticate.php
# index.php
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR
                 ."/home/linweb09/b/example.com-1050360506/user");
require_once "/htdocs/admin/authenticate.php";
```

And I run into these errors:

> [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:
>   require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/htdocs/admin/authenticate.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php:/home/linweb09/b/example.com-1050360506/user')
>   in /home/linweb09/b/example.com-1050360506/user/htdocs/admin/index.php on line 3
>
> [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:
>   require_once(/htdocs/admin/authenticate.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in
>   /home/linweb09/b/example.com-1050360506/user/htdocs/admin/index.php
>   on line 3

But it is in the correct location and the error says no such file or directory, so I'm not sure how I'm supposed to configure this.

I also tried these and I got the same errors:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR."/user");
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR."/");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the leading slash. `/htdocs/admin/authenticate.php` implies that you are working from root `/`. If you want it to search the include path, you need to use relative paths:

```
require_once "program_name/library/some_module.php";
require_once "htdocs/admin/authenticate.php";
```

Incidentally, you would only need to set the include path once per script - you dont need the `set_include_path()` line for every include, just once at the top of the script.

Comment: I tried `/`, `user/` and `(full-path)` as the set_include_path and I tried `htdocs/admin/authenticate.php` for each of those, still no luck :(

Comment: Actually, you were totally right! I just checked the log file again and its failing on the other includes which I need to update, thanks for your help :). (for others after me, it worked with the full-path i.e. `/home/linweb09/.../user`